# Autofac complex generic model registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I've been trying to register my DA classes with autofac. (We are switching from MEF to Autofac..) but I cannot get it to work. When I do a webapi call through swagger, the application just exits, no break to an exception or anything. The output tells me iisexpress exited with 'Access violation' But I think the real reason is faulty registration of the model with autofac.

the model is as follows:

```
public abstract class EntityDa<TEntity, TContext> : IEntityDa<TEntity>
   where TContext : IEntities
   where TEntity : class
{
   protected readonly TContext _entities;
   
   protected EntityDa(TContext entities)
   {
      _entities = entities;
   }
}
```

```
internal class PersonInfoDa : EntityDa<PersonInfo, IPersonDataEntities>, IPersonInfoDa
{
   ...

   public PersonInfoDa(IPersonDataEntities entities, IStockDa stockDa, IPersonRelationDa personRelationDa) : base(entities)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

I have a lot of these Da classes, all inheriting from EntityDa the same way as this example.

What would be the correct way to register these?
I have the following in my module (Which isn't working)

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(this.ThisAssembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityDa<,>))
.As(typeof(IEntityDa))
.InstancePerDependency
```

UPDATE:

It's a StackOverflowException that occurs. How can I find out what the root cause of this is?

Comment: You need to post the exception and stack trace.

Comment: The output tells me iisexpress exited with an 'Access violation' There is no stacktrace, the program gets killed. When I run it in a console, I receive a Stackoverflowexception, but again with no stacktrace.

Comment: The problem is there's not enough here to help you. We don't know what's in your assembly or what else changed. The exception is usually where you look to see where a problem happened. The code posted generally looks okay or would otherwise cause an Autofac exception. What happens if you don't register anything? What happens if you don't do assembly scanning and specifically register enough stuff to make one simple call work? We can't really debug by proxy through you and need more info.

Comment: I [Kind of] fixed it by injection everything as Lazy<>... When using MEF we also imported everything lazy. I know that there's still an underlying problem, otherwise a stackoverflow wouldn't occur right?, or can this happen when injecting way to many dependencies? We have over 1000 classes in our solution with injection constructors.